# Lines disappearing in c program

Tags: c

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and haven't found anything about this behavior online.  I'm thinking it is something C-language specific, so I'm putting it up here to try to learn what that is.  When the following function has it's name changed to main and is compiled and run on its own, it does exactly what I'm looking for:

```
void print_to_screen(void) {
    system("clear");
    char *usor;
    usor = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
    if(sizeof(getenv("USER")) > 8)
        return;
    usor = getenv("USER");

    FILE *inFile;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    char fileIn[30];
    sprintf(fileIn, "/home/%s/output3", usor);

    if((inFile = fopen(fileIn, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror(fileIn);
        return;
    }

    int lines = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, inFile) != NULL)
            lines++;
    if(lines == 0) {
        printf("Sortact empty. Press enter.");
        getchar();
        return;
    }
    rewind(inFile);

    for(i = 0; i <= PAGE; i++) {
        if(count == 0) {
            printf("%d accounts worked\n", lines);
            //sleep(2);
            printf("    %-8s %-8s  %8s   %8s  %8s  %8s\n", "begin", "end", "msg #", "activity", "response", "next_act");
            //sleep(2);
        }

        if(lines == count) {
            printf("End of output.  Press enter.");
            fclose(inFile);
            getchar();
            return;
        }
        fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, inFile);
        count++;
        printf("%3d %s", count, buf);

    }

    while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, inFile) != NULL) { 
        printf("q) to quit, Enter) for line-by-line feed, 'b') backup, *) next page\n");

        char c = getchar();
        if(c == 'b') {
                if(count == PAGE)
                    continue;
                system("clear");
                count -= 2;
                rewind(inFile);
                for(i = count; i > 0; i--) {
                    fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, inFile);
                    printf("%3d %s", count, buf);
                }
                continue;
        }
        else if(c == '\n') {
            if(lines == count) {
                    printf("End of output.  Press enter.");
                    fclose(inFile);
                    getchar();
                    return;
            }
            system("clear");
            count++;
            rewind(inFile);
            i = count;
            count = 0;
            for(; i > 0; i--) {
                fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, inFile);
                count++;
                printf("%3d %s", count, buf);       
            }
            continue;
        }
        else if(c == 'q') {
                return;
        }
        else {
            if(lines == count) {
                    printf("End of output.  Press enter.");
                    fclose(inFile);
                    getchar();
                    return;
            }
            system("clear");

            for(i = 0; i <= PAGE; i++) {
                if(lines == count) {
                    printf("End of output.  Press enter.");
                    fclose(inFile);
                    getchar();
                    return;
                }
                fgets(buf,BUFSIZ, inFile);
                count++;
                printf("%3d %s", count, buf);
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
    fclose(inFile);
}
```

However, when I run in as a separate function from the following switch statement, it cuts off the first two lines of output (the accounts worked and the header line):

```
while(c == 0) {
        printf("1) print to the screen, most recent first\n");
        printf("2) print to the screen, least recent first\n");
        printf("3) print to paper\n");
        printf("4) cancel\n");
        c = getchar();
        switch(c) {
            case '1' :
                sprintf(sort_c, "sort -r -k1.1,1.2 -k1.4,1.5 -k1.7,1.8 /home/%s/output2 > /home/%s/output3", usor, usor);
                free(usor);
                system(sort_c);
                print_to_screen();
                return 0;
            case '2' :
                sprintf(sort_c, "sort -k1.1,1.2 -k1.4,1.5 -k1.7,1.8 /home/%s/output2 > /home/%s/output3", usor, usor);
                free(usor);
                system(sort_c);
                print_to_screen();
                return 0;
            case '3' :
                sprintf(sort_c, "sort -k1.1,1.2 -k1.4,1.5 -k1.7,1.8 /home/%s/output2 > /home/%s/output3", usor, usor);
                system(sort_c);
                sprintf(print_c, "qprt -Plp3 /home/%s/output3", usor);
                system(print_c);
                free(usor);
                return 0;
            case '4' :
                free(usor);
                return 0;
            default :
                c = 0;
                system("clear");
                break;
        }
    }
```

I've tried removing the loop and about a billion other things, but nothing has helped the behavior.  Those first two lines were originally before the loop they are now in.  Those commented out sleep() statements showed me that those lines are both being printed -- one and then the other -- and THEN they are being cleared somehow.  If someone can help me understand what is going on, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

(Oh, and this is part of a larger program and the "usor" variable is going to be checked.  I know I would probably catch hell if I didn't add this haha.)

The expected output is this:

> 46 accounts worked
>       begin    end          msg #   activity  response  next_act   1 12:44:29 13:04:19  0012497389         CR                  CS   2
>   08:40:28 08:54:40  0012498082         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   3
>   08:40:06 08:40:22  0012500689         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   4
>   08:39:47 08:39:59  0011906009         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   5
>   08:39:31 08:39:43  0012199860         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   6
>   08:39:04 08:39:27  0012499803         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   7
>   08:37:58 08:38:50  0012514625         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   8
>   08:37:18 08:37:55  0012224477         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   9
>   08:37:03 08:37:15  0012169778         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  10
>   08:36:20 08:36:59  0012499231         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  11
>   08:36:06 08:36:17  0012501138         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  12
>   08:34:58 08:36:00  0012206191         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  13
>   08:34:20 08:34:51  0012349829         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  14
>   08:31:59 08:34:11  0012348605         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  15
>   08:31:22 08:31:54  0012431227         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  16
>   08:30:12 08:31:04  0012425863         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  17
>   08:29:13 08:30:02  0012420569         CR                  DS  18
>   08:07:07 08:29:07  0012414680         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  19
>   08:06:42 08:07:01  0012414680         CR                  DS  20
>   08:06:28 08:06:37  0012185000         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  21
>   08:05:26 08:05:49  0012206880         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  22
>   08:04:23 08:05:22  0011775414         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ q) to
>   quit, Enter) for line-by-line feed, 'b') backup, *) next page

Which is what I get when it's run as its own program.  This is what I get without it:

> 12:44:29 13:04:19  0012497389         CR                  CS   2
>   08:40:28 08:54:40  0012498082         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   3
>   08:40:06 08:40:22  0012500689         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   4
>   08:39:47 08:39:59  0011906009         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   5
>   08:39:31 08:39:43  0012199860         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   6
>   08:39:04 08:39:27  0012499803         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   7
>   08:37:58 08:38:50  0012514625         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   8
>   08:37:18 08:37:55  0012224477         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ   9
>   08:37:03 08:37:15  0012169778         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  10
>   08:36:20 08:36:59  0012499231         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  11
>   08:36:06 08:36:17  0012501138         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  12
>   08:34:58 08:36:00  0012206191         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  13
>   08:34:20 08:34:51  0012349829         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  14
>   08:31:59 08:34:11  0012348605         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  15
>   08:31:22 08:31:54  0012431227         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  16
>   08:30:12 08:31:04  0012425863         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  17
>   08:29:13 08:30:02  0012420569         CR                  DS  18
>   08:07:07 08:29:07  0012414680         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  19
>   08:06:42 08:07:01  0012414680         CR                  DS  20
>   08:06:28 08:06:37  0012185000         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  21
>   08:05:26 08:05:49  0012206880         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ  22
>   08:04:23 08:05:22  0011775414         ZZ        ZZ        ZZ q) to
>   quit, Enter) for line-by-line feed, 'b') backup, *) next page

And yes, I've run it through gdb a bunch of times and it isn't showing me how the screen is clearing.

Comment: For some (*specified!*) input, what is the expected *and* actual output? Have you tried running in a debugger and step through the code line by line while keeping an eye on variables and their values? You do know that when you use `getchar` to read a single character, it only reads a single character and leave the newline you probably used in the input buffer for the next input function to read?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I've edited my answer to reply to your questions.  Thanks for you time. Oh, and the input is exactly what is being printed to the screen, but from a file.

Comment: These are the lines that aren't being printed:       printf("%d accounts worked\n", lines);
printf("    %-8s %-8s  %8s   %8s  %8s  %8s\n", "begin", "end", "msg #", "activity", "response", "next_act")

Comment: There really are very many mistakes. `usor = malloc(9)` is OK, it points `usor` to 9 bytes of fresh memory. But then `sizeof(getenv("USER"))` means the size of a pointer (which is what `getenv` returns; this is only `> 8` if your machine addresses have more than 64 bits (or bytes of more than 8 bits? I don’t think that is allowed)! What you meant is `strlen`. Then `usor = getenv("USER")` switches `usor` away from the fresh memory (which you therefore leak) and points it at s different string containing the definition of USER in the environment. Start by getting your head round that lot.

Comment: @PJTraill I'm trying to learn to program, so forgive me for most of the mistakes for now if you can.  Valuable info though, so thanks.  +1

Comment: Glad to help, though while it is all important, I fear it does not help to solve your problem:(

Comment: Not the visible one anyway haha

Comment: You have identified the statements that are not having the desired effect, and these are controlled by `if(count == 0)`, so you need to check with gdb what `count` is when you reach that statement. (But if `PAGE < 0` you will never reach it — and you have not shown us where `PAGE` comes from.)

Comment: @PJTraill PAGE is defined as 21.  And count is 0.  When I uncomment the sleep(2) functions, both of those lines are printed -- the first for 4 seconds, the second for 2. After the second sleep is up, they disappear.

Comment: Notice that not even "1" in "1 12:44:29" on the first line is printed (from `printf("%3d %s", count, buf);`). Are you sure the file output3 does not contain any special characters which could cause the console to be cleared when buf is printed?

Comment: So perhaps they also appear if you step through that block in the debugger, and then disappear as a result of the next `printf`, which, as @peter suggests, may contain special characters (look at their integer values with gdb).

Comment: @peter sorry, the cut-paste-block code is not working for me.  That output has line numbers and everything's moved off.  But no, there are no special characters in the input file, only alpha-numeric.

Comment: One more idea: as @JoachimPileborg suggested, the input to getchar is not consumed entirely, and the '\n' is the input to the next getchar, which here might cause the block under "else if(c == '\n') {" to be run, where you have system("clear") and print the lines.

Comment: are you sure these system commands work as expected `sprintf(sort_c, "sort -r -k1.1,1.2 -k1.4,1.5 -k1.7,1.8 /home/%s/output2 > /home/%s/output3", usor, usor);` ...??

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work.  Thanks a lot though guys!

Comment: @ Nikos M yes, that file is perfect.  It's just printing to the screen (and, again, only when it's from that while loop) where it gets buggy.

Comment: If nothing else works I suppose one of the system("clear") calls has to be the culprit. Can you comment them out?

Comment: Hmmm, Is `\r` involved?

Comment: `char fileIn[30];   sprintf(fileIn, "/home/%s/output3", usor);` is unsafe.  Certain no overflow?

Comment: @chux on our AIX machine, the user can only have 8 characters for a username.  Plus we've had them signing in to the server and being sent right into the software we use -- so I'll be assigning them usernames.  I don't think \r is involved because it's all on a *nix, AIX -- which only uses \n, if I've got my facts straight.

Comment: @peter I'm home for the weekend now.  I'll check that out Monday, but again, those clears are there when I run that function alone and they don't cause an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried compiling your code myself. When you enter 1 or 2 as an input to your main program,`c = getchar();` (main, line 6) consumes only the first character, leaving '\n' in stdin, which is immediately consumed by getchar in `print_to_screen` on line 54. This causes `system("clear")` to be called (print_to_screen, line 74), clearing the header lines, and printing again lines of `output3` without the header, which makes it look as if the header disappeared. It does not happen if you run `print_to_screen` as the main function, as there is no extra input in stdin when you run it.

The easiest modification you can make to see it is to add `getchar();` right after `c = getchar();` (main, line 6) to remove the extra '\n' from stdin. But it is better to use `fgets` instead of `getchar`, in order to read the whole line at a time.

Also it is in general advisable to use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` (to avoid buffer overflow), `calloc` instead of `malloc` (to avoid integer overflow), and to always check the return value of allocation and `fgets`. And the `system` calls with user-supplied input are of course very sensitive due to potential command injection (though I know you said the input is safe). For more info, see CAVEATS in [sprintf(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=snprintf&apropos=0&sec=0&arch=default&manpath=OpenBSD-current) and [malloc(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=malloc&apropos=0&sec=0&arch=default&manpath=OpenBSD-current).

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I have a lot to learn yet about C.  I didn't think to check stdin itself, but was printing the buf array in gdb -- I'm not sure even how to check stdin, though I'll experiment with it this weekend or Monday.  I'm also not sure how print_to_screen, taking no args, would "consume" the newline character.  Is it the "clear" in default that's being run?  Again -- thanks very much!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. stdin as a file descriptor is common to all functions in C (in fact, the entire process), so when you enter "1" on the console, the OS sends two characters to your process: '1' and '\n'. getchar only reads '1', so '\n' is left to be read by following I/O functions (it stays either in a kernel buffer, or in a buffer of the C standard library). The next I/O call is getchar in print_to_screen, so it gets the '\n' without waiting for input, and system("clear") on line 74 is called (not the one in main).